# Error in performing Word2Vec in Python

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I'm totally new in Python and gensim. I'm trying to use word2vec from gensim in Python 3.4 on windows7 (64).

```
import csv
with open('Data.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
Word2VecTextTrain = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
   from gensim.models import Word2Vec
   model = Word2Vec( Word2VecTextTrain, size=100, window=3, min_count=5, workers=4)
```

"Data.csv" contains 30k rows of texts. These texts are either a complete or incomplete sentences including up to 20 words. Some of them may contain "/" or numbers.

I'm facing this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Home/PycharmProjects/Word2Vec Project/Word2Vec_2016_03_23", line 26, in <module>
     model = Word2Vec( Word2VecTextTrain, size=100, window=5, min_count=5, workers=4)
   File "C:\Users\Home\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\word2vec.py", line 431, in __init__
     self.build_vocab(sentences, trim_rule=trim_rule)
   File "C:\Users\Home\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\word2vec.py", line 497, in build_vocab
     self.finalize_vocab()  # build tables & arrays
   File "C:\Users\Home\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\word2vec.py", line 625, in finalize_vocab
     self.reset_weights()
   File "C:\Users\Home\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\word2vec.py", line 932, in reset_weights
     self.syn0[i] = self.seeded_vector(self.index2word[i] + str(self.seed))
   File "C:\Users\Home\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\word2vec.py", line 946, in seeded_vector
     once = random.RandomState(uint32(self.hashfxn(seed_string)))
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have no idea for the reason of this error. Any help is truly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I was not able to reproduce the error on my ubuntu machine, however [LineSentence](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.LineSentence) might suit you better:

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
from gensim.models.word2vec import LineSentence

Word2VecTextTrain = LineSentence('Data.csv')
model = Word2Vec(Word2VecTextTrain, size=100, window=3, min_count=5, workers=4)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, it gave me the same error.

Comment: would you be able to share the input file?